# How to map multiple SQL relationships to c# objects

Tags: c#, sql, slapper.automapper

I'm developing a C# WPF desktop application where I need to read/write to an SQL database (SQL server) regularly. Now I want to map the data from the database to objects in C#. I can't use Entity Framework so I'm doing all my data access through Dapper, slapper automapper and stored procedures.

As an example, I have modeled this sample database

[image]

The C# objects would look similar to this.

```
public class Manager {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public List<Facility> Facilities {get; set;}
} 

public class City {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description{ get; set; }
   public List<Facility> Facilities {get; set;}
} 

public class Facility {

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Now i query the Data from the Tables with Dapper in the underscore Notation from Slapper:

```
const string sql = @"SELECT 
                                    m.Name,
                                    m.Phone,
                                    m.ManagerId,
                                    f.FacilityId As Facility_FacilityId,
                                    f.WorkerCount As Facility_WorkerCount,
                                    f.SquareFoot As Facility_SquareFoot,
                                    f.Description As Facility_Description,
                                    c.CityId AS Facility_City_CityId,
                                    c.Name AS Facility_City_Name,
                                    c.Description AS Facility_City_Description,

                                    from Manager m  
                                    INNER JOIN  dbo.Facility f  ON  m.ManagerId = f.ManagerId
                                    INNER JOIN  dbo.City c  ON  f.CityId = c.CityId";


            using (System.Data.IDbConnection _connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connstrint"))
            {
               var test = _connection.Query<dynamic>(sql);
                Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Facility), new List<string> { "FacilityId" });
                Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(Manager), new List<string> { "ManagerId" });
                Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.AddIdentifiers(typeof(City), new List<string> { "CityId" });



                var testNetwork = (Slapper.AutoMapper.MapDynamic<Manager>(test) as IEnumerable<Manager>).ToList();
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
```

I understand that the mapping cant fully work because facility cant go to City in the Objects. Should i map twice ? one time from Manager down then from City ? Or is there another design pattern that i should use?

Comment: _I understand that the mapping cant fully work because facility cant go to City in the Objects_.  You have a foreign key joining the two, and you have the join in the SQL you posted. So I'm not sure what the question is

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dapper I will advice to do smaller query to retrieve the data rather than try to do complex mapping. I would write the code in this way:

```
const string sqlManager = @"SELECT 
                                    m.Name,
                                    m.Phone,
                                    m.ManagerId,
                                    from Manager m";  
 
const string sqlFacility = @"SELECT f.ManagerId,
                                    f.CityId,
                                    f.FacilityId,
                                    f.WorkerCount,
                                    f.SquareFoot,
                                    f.Description,
                                    from dbo.Facility f";

const string sqlCity = @"SELECT 
                                    c.CityId,
                                    c.Name,
                                    c.Description,
                                    from  dbo.City c";

using (System.Data.IDbConnection _connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connstrint"))
{
    List<Manager> managers = _connection.Query<dynamic>(sqlManager);
    List<Facility> facilities = _connection.Query<dynamic>(sqlFacility);
    List<City> cities = _connection.Query<dynamic>(sqlCity);

    foreach (var manager in managers)
    {
        manager.Facilities = facilities.Where(x => x.ManagerId == manager.ManagerId).ToList();
    }
    foreach (var city in cities)
    {
        city.Facilities = facilities.Where(x => x.CityId == city.CityId).ToList();
    }
}
```

As well the code above match yours but I will advice to use async/await to your calls specially, here is some sample call for dapper with stored procedure:

```
var mainTables = await _sql.LoadDataAsync<MainTable, dynamic>(
    "dbo.spMainTableGetAll",
    new { });

List<SubTable> subTables = await _sql.LoadDataAsync<SubTable, dynamic>(
    "dbo.spSubTableGetAll",
    new { });

foreach (var mainTable in mainTables)
{
    mainTable.SubTables = subTables.Where(x => x.MainTableId == mainTable.Id).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting doing the join in the app, not the database. For large datasets it makes sense to do joins in the database instead.

Comment: In general I agree with you but still depend on the requirements. The answer is specific to the question presented, if you look at the query in the question there is no actual relationship between city and manager so the data mapping between one query and two non-related objects is going to take similar processing time. I think is because of the relationship AutoMapper is struggling